# Terraform azurerm_kubernetes_cluster invalid or unknown key: network_profile

Tags: azure, networking, kubernetes, terraform

I need some help with setting Advanced Networking for **azurerm_kubernetes_cluster**

I've been using code from this page as an example 
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/kubernetes_cluster.html

The only difference is that I make a module from it for my purpose. All there rest is pretty the same

Problem is with

```
network_profile {
    network_plugin = "azure"
  }
```

After run terraform plan I received the error below:

```
Error: module.aks.azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.aks: : invalid or unknown key: network_profile
```

I will be glad for any help thx

ask.tf

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "aks" {
  name = “name-rg”
  location = “East US”
}

resource azurerm_network_security_group "aks_nsg" {
  name                = “name-nsg"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.aks.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.aks.name}"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "aks_vnet" {
  name                = “name-vnet"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.aks.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.aks.name}"
  address_space       = ["10.2.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "aks_subnet" {
  name                      = “name-subnet"
  resource_group_name       = "${azurerm_resource_group.aks.name}"
  network_security_group_id = "${azurerm_network_security_group.aks_nsg.id}"
  address_prefix            = "10.2.0.0/24"
  virtual_network_name      = "${azurerm_virtual_network.aks_vnet.name}"
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "aks" {
  name                = "aks-name"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.aks.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.aks.name}"
  dns_prefix          = “dns-name”

  linux_profile {
    admin_username = "${var.aks_admin_username}"

  ssh_key {
      key_data = "${var.aks_ssh_public_key_path}"
    }
  }

  agent_pool_profile {
    name            = "default"
    count           = "${var.aks_agent_count}"
    vm_size         = "${var.aks_vm_size}"
    os_type         = "${var.aks_os_type}"
    os_disk_size_gb = "${var.aks_os_disk_size_gb}"
    vnet_subnet_id = "${azurerm_subnet.aks_subnet.id}"
  }

  service_principal {
    client_id     = "${var.aks_client_id}"
    client_secret = "${var.aks_client_secret}"
  }

  network_profile {
    network_plugin     = "azure"
  }
}
```

Update:

```
Terraform v0.11.8
+ provider.azurerm v1.5.0          <---- Wrong version, should be v1.15.0
```

Comment: It would probably help someone who could answer this question if you specified the version of terraform _and_ provider you are using

Comment: Sorry forgot about it
Terraform v0.11.8
+ provider.azurerm v1.5.0

Comment: Ok problem solved
Wrong provider version
Should be -->   + provider.azurerm v1.15.0

Comment: @Adamo_O please provide your own answer and accept it

Answer (score 0):

- provider.azurerm v1.5.0          <---- Wrong version, should be v1.15.0

Answer (score 0):

Check your main.tf, if you have fixed the provider version, you need to take it out (see below) and test again.

```
provider "azurerm" {
 #version = "=1.5.0"
}
```

currently it should be 1.20.0